# VBA on KeyDown (key Enter) string is Null

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2010, keydown

Using MS Access 2010 (forms)
I have a simple textbox that will filter (via SQL) the database when the user presses an "Enter" key.

**THE PROBLEM**
The problem is that after I type in data and press the "Enter" key - the code sees the textbox as NULL (and not the value that's actually in the textbox).

But when I press the "Enter" key again - then everything works fine.

---

I need to make sure the code always executes on the first attempt

The name of my textbox is: `search_txt`

VBA:

```
Private Sub search_txt_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
   If (KeyCode = vbKeyReturn) Then
      filterResults (Me.search_txt.Value)
      Me.search_txt.SetFocus
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Textbox.Value` is not set until the textbox is updated by leaving the control, e.g. by pressing Enter or Tab.

To get the content while the user is typing, use the `Textbox.Text` property.

`Textbox.Text` is only valid when the textbox has the focus, but in your case this is always true.

Comment: Thanks! This works. I actually ended up getting it fixed by changing the event to "KeyUp" - but this works great if the user requires KeyDown